# For a real sequence $(x_n)$ if $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<1/2^n$ then $x_n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence, if $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$, show that $(x_n)$ converges.

*Proof attempt:* Let $\varepsilon>0$. First, since the sequence $\left(1/2^n\right)$ converges to zero there is an $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ so that if $n\ge n_\varepsilon$ then $1/2^n<\varepsilon/2$.

Now we show that this implies that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. We use mathematical induction for showing that $|x_n-x_{n+p}|<\varepsilon$.

*Base case:* $p=1$, By hypothesis we have $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<1/2^n<\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon$.

*Induction step:* Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Suppose $|x_n-x_{n+p}|<\varepsilon/2$. Since $|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p+1}|<1/2^{n+p}<1/2^n$, then we have $$|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p+1}|<\varepsilon/2,$$

combining with the inductive hypothesis and using the triangle inequality yields

$$|x_{n}-x_{n+p+1}|\le|x_{n}-x_{n+p}|+|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p+1}|<\varepsilon$$
$$|x_{n}-x_{n+p+1}|<\varepsilon.$$

Hence, for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ we can conclude that if $m>n_\varepsilon$ and $m>n$ then $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$. Thus $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, implying that it is convergent.

Is this proof right? I'm dubious particularly about how I show the sequence is Cauchy, the fact that $m$ has to be greater than $n$ makes me doubt.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving convergence by showing a sequence is Cauchy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954393/proving-convergence-by-showing-a-sequence-is-cauchy)

Answer (score 3):

When doing induction arguments, it is helpful to write down exactly what your induction hypothesis $P(p)$ is and how it depends on the variable $p$.
The way that you've written it is not very clear, and this is what's causing you to (correctly) be worried.

As I understand it, the precise induction hypothesis that you're proving is:

$P(p)$: For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}$ such that, for any $m \in [n, n+p]$, we have $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$.

By induction, you have proved that $P(p)$ holds for all $p \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}$.
However, this is not the same as the Cauchy condition: compare the following statments:

- $\forall p \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}\; \forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists n \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}\; \forall m\in [n, n+p]: |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$ (what you've proved)
- $\forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists n \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}\; \forall p \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}\; \forall m\in [n, n+p]: |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$ (Cauchy condition)

As an exercise, check that the sequence $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ satisfies your condition but not the Cauchy condition.

Basically, induction is not suitable for this problem.
A hint for how to proceed is to notice that
$$
|x_n - x_m|
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k} - x_{k+1}|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For all  $n$, $m$$>$$N_ε$, without loss of genarality, let m>n,

|$x_n$−$x_m$|$<=$|$x_n$ − $x_{n+1}$ + $x_{n+1}$ - $x_{n+2}$ + $x_{n+2}$ -...+ $x_{m-1}$- $x_m$|

$<=$|$x_n$ − $x_{n+1}$| + |$x_{n+1}$ - $x_{n+2}$|+...+|$x_{m-1}$ - $x_m$|

<$1/2^n$+$1/2^{n+1}$+$1/2^{n+2}$+...+$1/2^m$

<$1/2^n$ (1 - $1/2^{m-n}$)/(1-$1/2$) < $2/2^n$ < ε

Thus $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, implying that it is convergent.

Comment: $\le$ is typed with `\le`. And $x_{n+1}$ is typed with `x_{n+1}`. $\epsilon$ is `\epsilon`. You can  see a mathjax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

(Important edit: Damian is right, the induction itself is off in your proof. However, I still deem it informative to let my answer stay, for clarity about the symmetry argument that would've let you finish, were your statement true!)

Let's do as if you'd proven that, for $m > n \geq n_\varepsilon$: $|x_n - x_m| < \varepsilon$.

Now, if you let $n > m \geq \varepsilon$, then: $|x_n - x_m| = |x_m - x_n| < \varepsilon$. Basically, thanks to $|.\! |$, your statement is "symmetric" in $n$ and $m$, so it ends up being fine! (Remember, they're "mute" variables: I just named $n$ "$m$" and $m$ "$n$" in the first statement to arrive at the conclusion)

Finally, the case $n = m$ is trivial as $0 < \varepsilon$. And thus you can conclude the sequence is indeed Cauchy.